# Performance slowdown when posting recursively with boost::asio::post to simulate a loop

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have an application reading and processing millions of events from a data file in a regular `while(not done){ doProcessEvent(); }` loop. This loop runs on it's own thread, and additionally there is an io_service context thread doing some work. Somewhere deeply inside doProcessEvent() some work is posted on the io_service context.
Thus there are 2 threads sharing some data and causing some problems.
I am trying to move all the work to io_service thread.

I've modified the code, so that instead of using the while loop, processEvent() posts itself to io_service context :

```cpp
void EventProcessor::processEvent()
{
    if ( there_is_next_event )
    {
       doProcessEvent();
       boost::asio::post(context,[this]{ processEvent();});
    }
}
```

The change works well, except that I am seeing some performance slowdown.
The original 2 threaded setup processing ~7million events takes this time:

```
real    0m34.282s
user    0m34.123s
sys 0m0.132s
```

Single threaded io_service based configuration gives the following result:

```
real    0m40.630s
user    0m37.646s
sys 0m2.940s
```

i.e. with the single threaded approach I am seeing 10%+ slowdown in user space and also significant increase of system use.

Could someone shed some light on the nature of this slowdown? Given that my goal is to run everything on io_service context, is my approach reasonable? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Can you update your question to have a [mcve]?

Comment: You've replaced a simple `while` loop with a event queue, surely some slowdown is to be expected? Your code has become much more complex?

Comment: This is an absolute shot in the dark guess: But I'm guessing your `there_is_next_event` bool expression is always evaluating to `true`.

Comment: The code in the example is not meant to be reproducible. This question is at conceptual level. there_is_next_event has the same meaning as `! done` in the  while loop. I understand that the code is more complex, meanwhile the code reads from a file (which is very slow) and processes 7 million events and it gets about 20% performance degradation by switching to post. Is cost of post 20% of cost of reading a record from a file? Is there a better approach to achieve the goal?

Comment: @DmitriyKumshayev All questions concerning the slowness of a C++ application, code, etc. should be accompanied by the compiler options used to build the application, and especially the optimization levels used.  If you're timing an unoptimized build (or a "debug" build), then the timings you are showing are meaningless.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie both timings are for optimised builds